# Deleting items from a dynamically generated list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, list, dynamic

I'm rather new to jQuery, so forgive me if this is trivial.

I am generating a list of links dynamically based on information which is stored in a database. Next to every link I place a delete button. It's purpose is to firstly delete the information from the database, and then to remove itself and it's container from the html page. Now when I try to attach an event to each button, this doesn't seem to work for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated

So far I came up with the following code:

For the html part:

```
<div id="main-content">
    <div id="existing-content">
    </div>
    <div id="new-content">
        <p>
       <input type="button" id="newcat" value="Nieuwe Categorie" />
   </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then for the jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('getCategories.php', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Check if there are any categories in the database (this works)
        if (eval(data.categoriesPresent)) {
            // Append an ordered list of links to the div
            $('#existing-content').append('<ol id="categories"></ol>');

            // Append list items to the ordered list (this also works)
            for (i=0; i<data.categories.ids.length; i++) {

                // JSON call to get numerical id of a category
                var catId = data.categories.ids[i];
                var catName = data.categories.names[i];

                // Create a listing of all categories currently stored in the database
                $('#categories').append('<li id="listItem' + catId 
                    + '"><p><a href="category.html?catId=' + catId  
                    + '&catName=' + catName +'">Categorie: ' + catName
                    + '</a></label><input type="button" class="delete" id="cat"' + catId 
                    + ' value="Verwijder" ?></p></li>'
                );

               // Generate delete functions for all available categories (this DOESN'T work)
               $('#cat' + dataId).click(function() {
                   alert("WE GOT HERE");
                   $.ajax({
                       url : "deleteCategory.php?catId=" + data.categories.ids[i],
                       success : function() {
                           $('#listItem' + data.categories.ids[i]).remove();
                       }
                   });
               });
           }
       }
   });
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use live to bind events to dynamically created elements.

In your case use the class selector .delete to identify the delete buttons.

Also move the live method call out of the getJSON callback and into the document ready handler.

Your code should now look like below(added a better way to remove the li element on successful ajax call) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Generate delete functions for all available categories
     $(".delete").live("click", function() {
            var $this = $(this);
                    var catID = this.id.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
             alert("WE GOT HERE");
             $.ajax({
                     url : "deleteCategory.php?catId=" + catID ,
                     success : function() {
                             $this.closest("li").remove();
                     }
             });
     });

    $.getJSON('getCategories.php', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Check if there are any categories in the database (this works)
        if (eval(data.categoriesPresent)) {
            // Append an ordered list of links to the div
            $('#existing-content').append('<ol id="categories"></ol>');

            // Append list items to the ordered list (this also works)
            for (i=0; i<data.categories.ids.length; i++) {

                // JSON call to get numerical id of a category
                var catId = data.categories.ids[i];
                var catName = data.categories.names[i];

                // Create a listing of all categories currently stored in the database
                $('#categories').append('<li id="listItem' + catId 
                    + '"><p><a href="category.html?catId=' + catId  
                    + '&catName=' + catName +'">Categorie: ' + catName
                    + '</a></label><input type="button" class="delete" id="cat"' + catId 
                    + ' value="Verwijder" ?></p></li>'
                );
           }
       }
   });
   ...
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. This seems the way to go. However, I need to pass in the catId somehow. In the code above you simply put in data.categories.ids[i] in the live() handler. This does not seem to work: Firebug gives the error data.categories.ids[i] is not defined. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: @MJD: Updated the post. I assume your ID's are numeric.

Comment: More specifically: data is not defined

Comment: Cybernate: yes, the id's are numeric

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/).  They are very useful for generating data-driven lists.  You can then attach a delete button click handler to each item in the list via [jQuery live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and call your server-side delete method to remove from database.

To refresh the list after you delete, just rebind the list using the template you already defined.